# How to use onEdit function to trigger an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to script writing, but I'm trying to set up a script to send an email once a certain cell (A4) is populated within a certain sheet.

The trouble I'm having is getting the script to trigger - I understand that running it when not in the spreadsheet generates an error, I get no error message, but no email appears to be sent using this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {

var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
var spreadSheet = e.source;
var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Scanned');
var range = getRange('A4');
var column = e.range.getColumn();
var row = e.range.getRow();

  if(sheet == 'Scanned' && column == 1 && row == 4)

    MailApp.sendEmail('joey@gmail.com', 'Tipping Notification: '+(name), 'Notification email body '+(name));
  
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you don't understand about running it.  If you run it then you have to provide the event object other wise e doesn't exist.  And you can't use a simple trigger to run anything that requires permission.

Answer (score 4):

An onEdit trigger always requires a 'manual' edit of the spreadsheet. If the spreadsheet(cell) is populated by a formula, it will not fire the onEdit trigger.

Also, in order to send emails, you'll have to use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) onEdit trigger. [Simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) onEdit triggers cannot access services that require authorization.

Comment: That's exactly what it was - the trigger had to be installed in the code, and also set up within the 'triggers' menu for it to work! Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

There are some restrictions for using simple trigger, One is simple trigger cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization.

In order to use services that requires authorization, you need to create an Installable trigger. See this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) on how to create Installable Trigger.

Also, [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) returns a Sheet Object and **not the name of the edited Sheet**. This causes your code to skip sending email.

### Try this:

**Code:**

```
function onEditA4(e) {
  
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var editedCell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var name = e.source.getName();
  if(editedSheet == 'Scanned' && editedCell == "A4")
    MailApp.sendEmail('insert email here', 'Tipping Notification: '+(name), 'Notification email body '+(name)); 
}
```

**Example Trigger:**

[image]