# Google Apps Script: How to send a mail after a cell is edited?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, send

I've got an empty **Google Spreadsheet** and the following working **Apps Script code**:

```
// This function SUCCESSFULLY opens a message box whenever a cell is edited, it shows the row of the edited cell.
function onEdit(e) {
  Browser.msgBox(e.range.getRow());
}

// This function SUCCESSFULLY sends an email to 'john@doe.com' (this email address is changed for an actual registered address) upon being called.
function myTestFunction() {
  MailApp.sendEmail('john@doe.com', 'Test', 'Cell changed');
}
```

However, if I change the 'onEdit'-function to the following it doesn't work properly:

```
// This function SUCCESSFULLY opens a message box whenever a cell is edited, BUT IT DOES NOT SEND AN EMAIL.
function onEdit(e) {
  Browser.msgBox(e.range.getRow());
  MailApp.sendEmail('info@bpbl.de', 'Test', 'Cell changed');
}
```

**Why does the latter 'onEdit'-function NOT send an email?**

(Yes, I have checked my [remaining daily email quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), there is plenty left.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use onEdit function to trigger an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078373/how-to-use-onedit-function-to-trigger-an-email)

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been posted, and unfortunatly, you can't call the sendEmail function inside the simple trigger onEdit :(

[Google-apps-script will not send email inside an onEdit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163274/google-apps-script-will-not-send-email-inside-an-onedit-function/28171287)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers